Read timeout unexpected behavior
I am migrating my an API microservice and among the changes I have switched Flask with FastAPI.
I have measured and tested and it seems that every route of my application is faster on the new rewritten microservice, however for some reason which I haven't yet found out how to recreate I'm getting some unexpected behavior.
I have another microservice relying on the API microservice, it runs multiple calls synchronously and gets timeout sometimes (timeout=(1,1)).
The number of calls to the API microservice haven't changed with the migration, so it's odd to me because I expected everything to run faster.
Upon inspecting the stats of the container the memory usage seemed reasonable below 900mb, and didn't seem to grow so I think it's safe to assume it's not a memory leak issue.
I have somewhat managed to recreate the timeout that im getting from the microservice after running multiple threaded API calls to the microservice simultanieously and overloading it. But I feel like it's a completely different scenario because the timeout I'm getting is for running 5 API requests synchronously.
In both versions I'm using gunicorn that raises 16 workers of the FastAPI/Flask app.
The configuration settings for the new microservice are as follows:
bind = 0.0.0.0:8080
workers = 16
accesslog = '-'
loglevel = 'debug'
capture_output = True
reload = True
enable_stdio_inheritance = True
workerclass =         "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker"

Just to clarify the timeout exception isn't raised in the API microservice but at the microservice that calls it, the timeout setting is 1 second.
import requests

requests.request(url=url, method="GET", timeout=(1,1))

I tried scaling up the container resources, but I'm still getting timeout.
I suspect the gunicorn doesn't manage the workers correctly but the gunicorn configuration is identical to the old microservice which worked fine.

Have you considered to use asyncio and async endpoints ?
You can also try to tweak both worker_connections and timeout in Gunicorn Configuration.

if your service run on K8S, try reduce worker to a lower number (such as = number vcpu) and increase number threads
